# How to find $\phi$ for triple integral spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Having trouble calculating bounds and how to do it generally for other terms.

I've been asked to find the volume of the solid bounded by the sphere

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$

and the cones

$z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

$z = -\sqrt{3x^2 + 3y^2}$

I assume that $0 <= \rho <= 2$ and $0 <= \theta <= 2\pi$, but I don't know how to find $\phi$ for either cones.

Comment: You can do it geometrically, by drawing right triangles (for the first cone, you have a $z=r$, so it's an isosceles right triangle, and $\phi=\pi/4$. Alternatively, put spherical coordinates into the equation and you'll get  $\rho\cos\phi = \rho\sin\phi$, so $\cos\phi = \sin\phi$, so $\phi = \pi/4$. You can work on the other one.

Answer (score -1):

Using cylindrical coordinates, we have the equations $$\begin{align}
z^2&=4-r^2,\\
z&=r\\
z&=-\sqrt 3 r
\end{align}.$$

The first equation gives $4-r^2\ge 0,$ or $0\le r\le 2.$ Then the last two give $-\sqrt 3 r\le z\le r.$ Finally, we have $0\le \phi\le 2π,$ since all the equations are independent of $\phi.$

So you want to calculate the $$\int_0^{2π}\int_0^2\int_{-\sqrt 3 r}^r{r\mathrm dz \mathrm dr\mathrm d\phi.}$$

Comment: In the title I specified spherical coordinates, not cylindrical.

Comment: First, you're using European/physics $\phi$, when the OP wanted $\phi$ to be the angle from the positive $z$-axis. Second, the OP specifically asked for help in spherical coordinates. Third, your $dV$ is wrong.  Fourth, where are you using the region between the sphere and the cones? I didn't check the rest.

Comment: @Jack That's right. I thought it wasn't necessary. This gives you what you want eventually with as little work (perhaps littler).

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand your quibble. The ones one notation I ignore. But what do you mean about the differential of volume of the specified region not being correct in cylindrical coordinates? What is it supposed to be, then? Thank you.

Comment: $dV = r\,dz\,d\phi$ in cylindrical coordinates. But the serious complaint is that you're ignoring the sphere. You're finding the volume between the two cones inside a cylinder of radius $2$, nothing to do with the sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, well yes, that's true. I forgot the scaling jacobian $r.$ Thanks for that.